# Does java contain a data type named "Item"?

Tags: java, types

I'm reading the book [Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X) and they mentioned a data type `Item`. However, I can't find it in any of the API. Does "Item" data type exist in java?

Comment: Don't skip parts of the book. Like the part where he defined `Item`

Comment: You could easily have [answered this question for yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index-files/index-9.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of. They probably just defined that data type in the book to show some concept, but it's definitely not a data type in standard Java.

Answer (score 22):

On page 124, Sedgwick writes

"The name Item is a type paramter, a symbolic placeholder for some concrete type to be used by the client."

```
public class FixedCapacityStack<Item>
```

It's just a Generic Type:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

Sedgwick uses "Item" instead of "T" because a Stack of "Item" was easier to read than a Stack of "T".  The point is you can put anything in there, although according to the Java documentation you should follow a naming convention:

E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
K - Key
N - Number
T - Type
V - Value
S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

which clearly he decided not to!

Comment: Just found your (very good) answer.  I'd chide Sedgwick for going against the typical idiom used by Java developers, including Joshua Bloch.  If he had used the conventional values it would have been immediately clear that it was a generic parameter.  Great citation from you.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no Item in the JDK 6 javadocs.  That must be a custom class that Sedgewich wrote.  Maybe you mean the ITEM interface on page 272 of the 4th edition:

http://books.google.com/books?id=hyvdUQUmf2UC&pg=PA272&lpg=PA272&dq=sedgewick+Item+class&source=bl&ots=kASI71PjAc&sig=BACGl1Q9nj43vhPwG8RVtO7euwI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DnYIT42GDqTX0QGthpSTAg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 6):

Although in skepticist circles it is a well known fact that the non-existence of an entity cannot be proven, I would dare say with relative certainty that the answer to your question is "No."

Comment: You could go some way to proving the non-existence (at least as a standard data-type) by looking at the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index-files/index-9.html.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, but the believer will always say "have you looked in the _right_ docs?"

Answer (score 0):

Amazon DynamoDB supports a datatype called *Item*. [Working with Items in DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html)

With help of this Item in Java, you can retrieve all the items from the DynamoDB and even more useful methods we can call upon this Item are like,

asMap() - Returns all attributes of the current item as a map.

attributes() - Returns all attributes of the current item as a map.

toJSON(),

toJSONPretty() etc.