# is <Foo> the same as <T>

Tags: java, generics

First I thought java had a type or class named Item, but it appears it has not:
[Does java contain a data type named "Item"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771238/does-java-contain-a-data-type-named-item)

It appears I can use anything between <>, no matter if it exists or not.

What I wonder, is:

```
class Foo<Item> {

}


Foo<Vec2D> foo = new Foo<Vec2D>();
```

The same as:

```
class Foo<T> {

}


Foo<Vec2D> foo = new Foo<Vec2D>();
```

?

Comment: Does my answer give you everything you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use any identifier as the parameter name, however using a single letter is less confusing as it less likely to be mistaken for a class name.

Oracle's [Generic types tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) has the following recommendation:

> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed the same. It's just a way to give a certain name to an unknown generic type.

From the Java Tutorials' [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html):

> A generic class is defined with the following format:
>
> `class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }`
>
> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.
>
> ...

There are also some *naming conventions* hinted there:

> By convention, type parameter names are single, uppercase letters. This stands in sharp contrast to the variable naming conventions that you already know about, and with good reason: Without this convention, it would be difficult to tell the difference between a type variable and an ordinary class or interface name.
>
> The most commonly used type parameter names are:
>
> - E - Element (used extensively by the Java Collections Framework)
> - K - Key
> - N - Number
> - T - Type
> - V - Value
> - S,U,V etc. - 2nd, 3rd, 4th types
>
> You'll see these names used throughout the Java SE API and the rest of this lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the same. with Generics, the name in brackets is only the Name of a Type you're going to use.

Like the name of a variable does not matter to the code, the name of a type doesn't matter either.